# How to dim a background in react native modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Following is my created react native Modal and still couldn't find how to dim the background and transparent around pop-up modal.I am not using any external libraries and trying to find solution without libraries.Is it possible to do with on this way?

[image]

## My Modal Component

```
render() {
let modal = this.state.modalType=='skill'? <SkillModal /> : <TrialModal />;
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Modal
      animationType='slide'
      onRequestClose={() => console.log('no warning')}
      presentationStyle="FormSheet"
      transparent
      visible={this.state.showModal}
    >
      <View>
        <View style={styles.modalView} >
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.closeModalFunc}
          >
            <Text style={styles.closeText}>X</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View>
            {modal}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </View>
  );
}
```

## Modal Component Style

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../../theme/colors';
import metrics from '../../../theme/metrics';
import {container} from '../../../theme/base';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
 backgroundColor: colors.background.gray,
},
modalView: {
 backgroundColor: colors.background.white,
 margin: 40,
},
closeText: {
  backgroundColor: colors.background.purpleishBlue,
  color: colors.background.white,
  borderRadius: metrics.avatar.small,
  width: 32,
  padding: 6,
  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
  textAlign: 'center',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: colors.background.white,
 },
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: Have you tried making modal `transparent={false}`?

Comment: yeah!! but then modal gets full screen.

Comment: @AsbarAli - Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 65):

I solve this one by create my own component MyPopup like below

```
class MyPopup extends React.PureComponent {

render() {
    return (
        <Modal 
            animationType="fade"
            transparent={true}
            visible={this.props.visible}
            >
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}}
```

Then I use it like

```
<MyPopup visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
<View style={{
    width: '90%',
    height: 50,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    elevation: 20,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 4,
}}>
    <Text>Hello, This is my model with dim background color</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: hi, but the modal doesnt cover the status bar. do you have solution for that?

Comment: It doesn't covers the whole screen

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by setting `transparent={true}` in the Props of the modal and by setting a 50% transparency in the style of the Modal's main View: `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'`

Comment: I think this is the most succinct and clear way to do it.  It affects no other components and the logic is simple.

Comment: It's a good answer but keep in mind that it won't apply to the header of the phone if you have a background there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I had to set `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'` on the ScrollView nested inside the modal

Answer (score 32):

You can programmatically set the opacity of your main `View` when `Modal` is visible.

```
<View style={[styles.container, this.state.showModal ? {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'} : '']}>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried it. but It doesn't make sense because background of the model is a parent component.

Comment: Where have you added this condition? You need to add this to your main parent `View` component. Not Modal's `View`

Comment: Yeah I added to the main view.But nothing changed. 'Test screen' text is on the parent component. not in this current component. it will work if those texts are in the current component

Comment: this is the correct answer since animation doesn't work in the same order as the foreground

Answer (score 13):

I managed to get a transparent dark background wich close the modal when you click on it.
I use a first external container in the modal element, which has full screen dimensions.
In it, the inner container has a box size and is centered in the screen.

Here the code (react: v16.13, react-native: v0.63.2)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View} from 'react-native';
import {style} from './style';

const MyModal = ({visible, onDismiss}) => {
  return (
    <Modal visible={visible} transparent>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onDismiss()}>
        <View style={style.modal}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={style.modalInner}>
              <Text>Something in the modal</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default MyModal;
```

The `onDismiss` is a callback toggling the value of the `visible` variable given to this component from his parent.

`TouchableWithoutFeedback` adds the `onPress` event handling on the containers. The external one respond on click, to close/dismiss the modal. The inner one do nothing (default behavior when `onPress` is not given).

With the style :

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export const style = StyleSheet.create({
  modal: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  },

  modalInner: {
    height: 200,
    padding: 35,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
});
```

Note that the parent element of my `<MyModal>` is the root `<View>` of my app, with the style `{flex: 1}`.

Answer (score 11):

I created a container style then I applied the rgba values for `backgroundColor` e.g:

```
modalContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    //backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
```

Then inside the modal I created my actual modal dialog with rounded corners (I achieved this by adding another  element inside the modal content and gave it a white background with rounded corners).

Comment: I found by containing components I can control the style hierarchy in this way.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to this question

Answer (score 9):

With [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal), you can use backdropOpacity property to dim background when modal is visible

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

function ModalTester() {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };

  render() {
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Button title="Show modal" onPress={toggleModal} />

    <Modal isVisible={isModalVisible} backdropOpacity={0.3}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>Hello!</Text>

        <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={toggleModal} />
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </View>
);
  }
}

export default ModalTester;
```

Answer (score 6):

I just Wrap the whole modalView in another View and simply apply background to it

```
<View style={styles.modalbackdrop}>   
   <View style={styles.modalView}></View>
</View>
```

and apply following

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
height: '100%',
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<View style={{opacity: modalVisible? 0.5 : undefined}}>
    <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
           setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        ...
    </Modal>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add **statusBarTranslucent** props to Modal component and set it to true. Then you will get your desired output. No need to set **transparent** props to true or any other tedious styles.

Comment: According to react native docs that prop only changes if the modal should go under the status bar, the question is about the background.

Answer (score -1):

React native provides a prop you can apply to the component

```
activeOpacity={0.9}
```

Which you can set to whatever you'd like